# Execute SQL Task in SSIS string parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssms, business-intelligence

I created two string variables (tot and tot_value) and assigned a value (tot = MyVal) for testing. Then I created an Execute SQL Task which takes (tot) as parameter and the value returned is saved in tot_value.

**In the General Tab**, i set:
ResultSet to Single row. 
SQL Source Type to Direct input 
 Query is listed below.

**In Parameter Mapping**
 I selected my *tot* variable with Input Direction
SQL_VARCHAR Data Type 
1 as Parameter Name (Since i am using ODBC)
Size set to default -1.

**In Result Set**
Result Name to 1
Variable Name to *tot_value*.

If in the query I hard code 'MyVal' i get the correct result, however when I use ? to use my variable as a parameter, I always get a 0 returned.

**Note that** my tot variable is set to MyVal
*Any clue of what I might be missing? Thanks in advance*

```
  select TOP 1 CAST('' + ISNULL((SELECT distinct type_of_transfer_code
FROM SYSTEM.history_program_transfer
WHERE type_of_transfer_value = ?),'') AS VARCHAR(100)) as type_of_transfer_code
FROM SYSTEM.table_facility_defaults
```

Comment: Try changing the size of the parameter to the maximum possible length of the variable instead of -1.

Comment: Hi, I tried setting the length to a 100 and to 8000 after, neither worked.

Comment: I've had Execute SQL Tasks struggle with embedded parameters. You might try : `DECLARE @interimVariable varchar(100) = ?;` and then `...type_of_transfer_value = @interimVariable...` Might work. Won't hurt to try.

Comment: Seems not like an option for me since I am using an ODBC connection to a CACHE DB which does not support declaration of variables. Unless I create a copy of the table in the SQL DB and query the data from there

Comment: I was just playing around with this, and using a minimally similar subset of your criteria, I found that my result set variable was only receiving one character. I haven't figured out why yet, and I have to stop now but thought I'd pass that finding on to you to see if you're in the same boat. It eliminates some culprits, anyway. Maybe drop your leading space, or replace it with something else and see if that's what comes through.

Comment: Had to migrate data to SQL Server then used Eric's suggestion to finish it up. I would still like to know why it wouldn't work with using "?" in the WHERE clause. Anyways, this will do it for now. Thanks all.